# Any way to select a region using `S-down-mouse-1` without saving the region as a kill?

Tags: region, copy-paste, mouse, kill-ring

Using emacsw32.

The usual suggested way to make a selection using `S-down-mouse-1` is to bind that to `mouse-save-then-kill`.

Is there a similar command which selects a region, but does not save the region?

The goal is to have the following scenario:

I have some text in the kill ring. I make a selection by holding shift and clicking the left mouse button. I delete the selection using `<delete>`. Then I paste something (using `cua-paste`) and this something is not the same as the region I just deleted.

Comment: What about `(global-set-key [S-drag-mouse-1] (lambda (click) (interactive "e") (let (mouse-drag-copy-region) (mouse-set-region click))))`?

Comment: That didn't work. Shift + left mouse button, followed by delete and cua-paste produces the text that has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

1. Start `emacs-w32 -Q`
2. Paste the following code into the `*scratch*`-buffer:

```el
(progn
  (cua-mode)
  (global-set-key [S-drag-mouse-1] (lambda (click) (interactive "e") (let (mouse-drag-copy-region) (mouse-set-region click))))
  (global-set-key [S-down-mouse-1] 'mouse-set-point))

111
222
333
```

3. Execute the `progn`-form with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>
4. Select the string "111" with `mouse-1` (`down` and `drag`) and copy with <kbd>C-c</kbd>
5. Shift-select the string "222" with `S-down-mouse-1` and `S-drag-mouse-1`
6. Kill the shift-selected string with <kbd>del</kbd>
7. Insert the string "111" from the `kill-ring` with the key <kbd>C-v</kbd>

If I execute <kbd>M-x</kbd> `emacs-version` I get:

`GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) of 2015-04-10 on desktop-new`

It also works with

`GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on toyol, modified by Debian`

Note, that <kbd>del</kbd> runs `delete-forward-char` while C-x runs indirectly `cua-cut-region` which copies the cut text to `kill-ring`.

`delete-forward-char` **deletes** the active region if the variable `delete-active-region` is set to a non-nil value **other than `'kill`**. The standard setting is `t`.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't really work. Using GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what `S-down-mouse-1` has to do with selecting text. In `emacs -Q` (no init file), holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing `mouse-1` brings up `mouse-appearance-menu` (menu **Change Default Buffer Face**).

Anyway, you can do what you want using a command that calls `delete-region`:

```
(defun del-region-no-kill (beg end)
  "Delete the active region without killing it."
  (interactive "r")
  (delete-region beg end))
```

For example:

```
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'del-region-no-kill)
```